# Does GAE offer default quantitative abuse protection?

Tags: security, google-app-engine

If I were to say, upload the [sample application](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/introduction.html) written in Python, would Google protect me from malicious bots trying to eat up my resources? DoS attacks?

Exactly how much security can I expect from Google?

**background:**

I've read [this article](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/dos.html) and it looks like you have the option to manually request certain blocks of IP addresses to be blocked. I am not very knowledgeable when it comes to security, but I would have imagined that  Google would automatically blacklist suspicious IPs. But then I realized I really didn't know what kind of protection Google did provide, if any, so I thought it might be best to ask.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822247/is-it-possible-to-prevent-dosing-on-google-app-engine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They will not protect you.  You have to manually block the IP's and even that requires a redeploy of code (there's no UI for it).

I'm speaking about this from the experience of a surprise $1000 / week bill on a normally $5 / day app.  I had upped the limit to do a major import of data consuming a ton of resources and then not set it back down again.  Big mistake.  They did give me system credits for less than a third of it, not sure if that was due to this being the day after the billing change (pre-billing change it wouldn't have cost more than the $5 / day) or if it's general policy after a DoS attack.

Even if you have the bill set to be low, they will just stop serving your resources as soon as your bill is eaten up and no warning email will be sent requiring you to use a third-party monitoring service or watch your site 24/7, making the DoSers job much easier.

Bottom line: tread carefully.